# Importing functions from other c file without a header

Tags: c, import

My assignment is to create a program that essentially tests the library I created in another c file.  My issue is how I go about calling the library without the header. The library program is:

```
/* 
Program: statlib.c 

A Statistical library consisting of the following 
seven functions: mean, variance, standard deviation, 
sort, minimum value median, and max value. 
*/

#include <math.h>

/* Calculates the mean value of the data in the list */
double mean(int totnum, double data[]) {
double meanval, sum;
int i;
sum = 0.0;
for(i=0; i<totnum; i++) {
    sum += data[i];
}
meanval = sum/totnum;
return meanval;
}

// Calculate the variance of the data in the list
double variance(int totnum, double data[]) {
double meanval, sum, var;
int i;

meanval = mean(totnum, data);
sum = 0.0;
for(i=0; i<totnum; i++){
    sum += (data[i] - meanval)*(data[i] - meanval);
}
var = sum/(totnum-1);
return var;
    }

/* Calculate the standard deviation of data in the list */
double stdDeviation(int totnum, double data[]) {
double var, std;
var = variance(totnum, data);
std = sqrt(var);
return std;
}

/* Sorts the array data in ascending order. */
void sort(int totnum, double data[]) {
int i, j;
double temp;

/* find the smallest value in the reaming part of the array
in each iteratio staring with data[i]. */
for(i = 0; i < totnum-1; i++) {
    /* compare with data[i] with data[j], swap their values */
    for(j = i+1; j < totnum; j++) {
        /* when data[i] > data[j], swap their values */
        if(data[i] > data[j]) {
            temp = data[i];
            data[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
}

/* Calculates the min value of an array. */
double minValue(int totnum, double data[]) {
double minval;
int i;

/* start at the intial value */
minval = data[0];
for(i = 1; i < totnum; i++) {
    if(data[i] < minval) {
        minval = data[i];
    }
    return minval;
}
}

/* Calculate the median of an array. Must be sorted first using the sort
function.*/
double median(int totnum, double data[]) {
double medianval;

if(totnum % 2) {
    medianval = data[totnum/2];
}
else {
    medianval = (data[totnum/2 -1] + data[totnum/2]/2.0);
}
return medianval;
}

/* Returns the maximum value of an array. */
double maxValue(int totnum, double data[]) {
double maxval;
int i;
maxval = data[0];
for(i = 1; i < totnum; i++) {
    if(data[i] > maxval) {
        maxval = data[i];
    }
}
return maxval;
}
```

The program that I'm using to test the first program is:

```
/* 
Program: teststatlib.c 
This program tests my statlib.c program in order to
verify whether or not it is in working order.
*/

#include <stdio.h>

/* add code from statlib.c */
#pragma importf <statlib.c>

/* Declare extern functions so that the can be used */
extern double mean(int totnum, double data[]);
//extern double variance(int totnum, double data[]);
//extern double stdDeviation(int totnum, double data[]);
//extern void sort(int totnum, double data[]);
//extern double minValue(int totnum, double data[]);
//extern double median(int totnum, double data[]);
//extern double maxValue(int totnum, double data[]);

int main() {
int input[] = {30,90,100,84,72,40,34,91,80,62};
int totnum = sizeof(input)/sizeof(double);

printf("The unsorted array is %d.", input);
printf("The mean is ");
mean(totnum, input);
}
```

Comment: Why not make (or generate) a header?

Comment: Why doesn't it work as written? What errors are you getting?

Comment: It gives me the error, "undefined reference to 'mean' ". Which leads me to believe that I did not import the library correctly.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Your use of `extern` is correct.  If you told the compiler to compile both files at the same time, then it should work.  It sounds like it's a detail of your development environment, because your code looks pretty good.  What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I find your question confusing because you didn't state your problem very well.  In fact you never asked a question.  Maybe I can still be a little helpful.

A few things that you can fix:

- `sizeof(input)` not `sizeof(input[])`
- the second to last print line does not do what you want.  If you remove the `[]` then it will compile and print the address of the array (which is not what I think you want).  You probably want to print each element of the array and you should consider doing it in a `for` loop.  What you have looks very python-esk, but is not how we do things in c.
- in your last line, you call `mean()` as if you expect it print something.  I think you want to combine the last two lines to `printf("The mean is %f\n", mean(totnum,input));`
- `input` needs to be declared as an array of type `double`.  (also, you'll need to change `sizeof(int)` to `sizeof(double)` in the line below that)

I managed to compile and run your program in linux with the command `gcc teststatlib.c statlib.c`.  I don't recognize `#pragma importf <statlib.c>` and that makes me suspect you might be using a development environment that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: I've fixed the issue of removing the brackets before you commented I simply forget to edit my code.  As far as using '#pragma importf <statlib.c>' I was basing that off some site which I can't find currently.  How would this normally be done? I am very new to programming.